# How does Zenitsu's speed compare to Hashiras?

Tags: demon-slayer

There is an image circulating in internet about the speed of hashiras ranked, stated by Kimetsu No Yaiba author. In the last episode of the anime, we see both Zenitsu and Tengen moving very fast and cutting things in a flash. Supposedly Tengen is faster than Zenitsu, but there are some posts around saying once Zenitsu masters form #7 in the manga, he becomes the fastest demon slayer. Is this true?

How does Zenitsu's speed compare to Hashiras, is there info about this?

Comment: This reddit post might give you a start: https://www.reddit.com/r/KimetsuNoYaiba/comments/ixh7vw/how_fast_is_zenitsu/

Comment: one can only speculate. I don't think there's any clear info on this.